# Where do I find the Double-Action Revolver (unlocked in GTA Online) in Red Dead Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online, red-dead-online

I unlocked the Double-Action Revolver in GTA Online and completed the challenge and then I logged in RDO with the same Social Club account but I have no idea where to find the Double-Action Revolver. Any solutions?

Comment: You need to buy it, right? Try your local gunsmith. What's your progress in RDO so far (what chapter)? You probably didn't unlock the gun, you unlocked a customization on it. That's what's new, not the gun itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can buy it in all gunsmiths from the start of Chapter 3 onwards, you must complete the "A Strange Kindness" mission.